# Field to store a list of links

Tags: custom-field-types

I'm looking for a way to store a simple list of links (add/remove) in a single field on a basic Custom List. My team has extensive custom field development experience and we've built such fields before, but for this particular solution I am trying to avoid maintaining any custom code. Commercial or OSS (a la CodePlex) solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a picker type interface like the hyperlink column provides? If not, a plain text, multiple line of text column will work. You might need to tweak the CSS a little to make the box wider so the links are more visible.

Comment: Need something that feels a little more "list-y" for the end users.

Comment: Url enter-> url -> enter url -> enter and then maybe present it differently on the dispform (like with jQuery, for each and build a UL/LI)?